# XQuery Expression - Screen scraping - Saxon / JTidy

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xquery, saxon

I am working on a Java Web Scraper which uses Jtidy/Saxon. The Tidy Parsed DOM is sent to Saxon with a XQuery Expression to extract data. I am having difficulty with the XQuery expression.

The website is http://www.pacra.com.pk/reports.php. I want to extract all of the table data, it has to be done using XQuery to work with an old system.

Essentially what I want is Loop through all `tr` tags at this XPath `//*[@id="mainDiv"]/div/table/tbody`

return the `tr` tag 
Loop through all `td` tags in each `tr` 
return text in first 6 `td` tags 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

So far what I've came up with is

```
for $tr in //table/tbody
    for $row in $tr/child::tbody/child::tr
        return <tr><td>{data($row/td[1])}</td>
            <td>{data($row/td[1])}</td>
            <td>{data($row/td[2])}</td> 
            <td>{data($row/td[3])}</td>
            <td>{data($row/td[4])}</td>
            <td>{data($row/td[6])}</td>
```

My syntax is obviously wrong I am trying to learn XQuery but finding this website is vastly different than the tutorial sample XML.
If anyone can help it will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably doesn't help you that the HTML of that website is invalid, for example:

```
<table align="center" width="1024px">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" ><div id="mainDiv"><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
```

Note the new `html` page appearing inside the `<div id="main">` tag. Also I don't think the data that you want is actually in the div with the `id="main"`!

Regardless, you should be able to query it with something like:

```
declare namespace h = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

for $tr in /h:html/h:html[2]/h:body/h:div/h:table/h:tr
return
    <tr>{
        $tr/h:td[position() le 6]
    }</tr>
```

I used the EXPath HTTP Client to retrieve and tidy the HTML into XML, so the following worked for me:

```
import module namespace http = "http://expath.org/ns/http-client";
declare namespace h = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

for $tr in http:send-request(<http:request href="http://www.pacra.com.pk/reports.php" method="get"/>)[2]/h:html/h:html[2]/h:body/h:div/h:table/h:tr
return
    <tr>{
        $tr/h:td[position() le 6]
    }</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, with your example I was able to write my own version without tidying with EXPath HTTP Client. Exactly what I needed.